# Which is more common, "self-responsibility" or "personal responsibility"? (in the workplace)

Tags: word-choice, translation, german

I'm trying to figure out what the best translation is for the German word "Eigenverantwortung" in a workplace context. A literal translation would be self-responsibility but I've also seen personal responsibility or personal accountability.

Which one would you say is most commonly used for people who take responsibility for their own actions, actively do their part, take charge etc.?

Comment: It could be *initiative* or *personal responsibility* or *self-motivation* depending on the emphasis (and whether you're looking for HR/job-advertisement jargon or something more general). Can you provide an example sentence (in English)? *Motivated self-starter* is another bit of jargon, but I don't think a human being would ever use it.

Comment: For example:

Teams with high personal responsibility are more productive, more proactive and invest more.

Look at these five tips for improving personal responsibility.

Comment: Even the word *accountability* alone may cover it.

Comment: You haven't shown an example usage, but I suggest *conscientious*.

Comment: I mean... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=self+responsibility%2Cpersonal+responsibility&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for information of a nature easily obtenable from Google ngram